# Create a called method in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

For example, I am calling a method in my main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method();
}
```

I press Alt+Enter, I click on create method, press Enter and I have a method created.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method();
}

private static void method() {
}
```

Do Netbeans has a shortcut, other than Alt+Enter  +  Enter to generate a method? Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with using `ALT` + `ENTER` ?

Comment: `Alt+Enter+Enter` itself is a shortcut. The conventional way is to type complete method.